# ANSI C strncpy messing up screen output and other variables' values

Tags: c, ansi-c, strncpy

Using ANSI C, screen is messing up after the `strncpy`. Also if I try to print any `int` variable values become incorrect. However if I move the print line before `strncpy` everything is fine.

Does anybody know why?

```
#define TICKET_NAME_LEN 40

struct stock_data 
{
    char ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1];
};

struct stock_data user_input;

char tname[TICKET_NAME_LEN+1] = "testing it";

strncpy(user_input.ticket_name, tname, TICKET_NAME_LEN);
```

Comment: most likely the problem is in the code you are not showing.

Comment: the rest of the code is related with multiple header and c files. I simplified the code and posted it. Something wrong with `buffer` and `strncpy` but I couldn't figured it out.

Comment: the code you have shown looks ok, maybe you could show how you print out the strings.

Comment: Removing unnecessary and unrelated code is great, but when you do that, remove things so that you're left with a short, complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem. The fact that you're having this issue shows that you're probably not yet able to determine what in the code is causing it, so posting something compilable which demonstrates the problem is the only way for you to know that you haven't left important code out.

Comment: Read up on how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) that reproduces the problem and does not contain anything unnecessary.  It can be quite fun ruthlessly eliminating code, reducing a few thousand lines down to 30 that encapsulate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms you are describing are the classic ones for a copy that is out of control.  However, the real source of your problem is almost certainly not in the code you show.

The only possible issue with the code you show is that `strncpy()` does not guarantee that the output (target) string is null terminated.  This won't hurt with the code shown (it doesn't do anything untoward), but other code that expects the string to be null terminated that blithely copies it without ensuring that there's space may go trampling other memory because the string is not null terminated.

If the input (source) string is longer than the space specified (in this case more than TICKET_NAME_LEN bytes long), then `user_input.ticket_name` will not be null terminated except by accident.  If it is shorter, then `user_input.ticket_name` will be null padded to the length TICKET_NAME_LEN bytes.

If this is the problem, a very simple fix is to add the line:

```
user_input.ticket_name[TICKET_NAME_LEN] = '\0';
```

after (or even before, but it is more conventional to do it after) the `strncpy()`.

However, to run into this problem, you'd have to be trying to copy a name of 41 or more characters into the ticket name member of the structure.

It is much more likely that something else is the cause of your trouble.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.24.2.4 The `strncpy` function
>
> ¶2 The strncpy function copies not more than `n` characters (characters that follow a null
>   character are not copied) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the array pointed to by
>   `s1`.<sup>308)</sup> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> ¶3 If the array pointed to by `s2` is a string that is shorter than `n` characters, null characters
>   are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by `s1`, until `n` characters in all have been
>   written.
>
> <sup>308)</sup> Thus, if there is no null character in the first n characters of the array pointed to by s2, the result will not be null-terminated.

Comment: "but it is more conventional to do it after" -- because this way, you *know* that you've null-terminated the buffer (and potentially lost the last character) vs. getting the numbers wrong in strncpy, and accidentally removed the null terminator.